# Google NDB: How to Make a Keys Only Query By Id

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Id like to check whether an entity still exist in a NDB DataStore. I have the Entity's ID and I do not this operation to count as a read operation but I can't see how to make a keys_only = True query while using get_by_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to use it with `.get()` operation.

You can do it with query but you will get one read operation anyway, and queries are slower and don't use memcache. But probably still worth to use if your entity is big enough.

```
Foo.query(Foo.key == ndb.Key(Foo, '11nNpmkaQk3iJ1kIFNQXAM')).get(keys_only=True)
```